# Data center part in OAuth authentication in mailchimp API

Tags: mailchimp

While exploring API documentation we found that,Datacenter part for API URL corresponds to last part of the API key.

Can this applicable even if authentication method is used as OAuth2?

Should we use metadata URI 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/metadata' to obtain DC string for OAUth2 authentication method?

Which way is valid one for OAUth2? is  DC from  API key or from matadata URI?

Thank you.

Regards,
Sonia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API key are given for exploring api, but in oauth2 flow from mailchimp end, access token received act as an apikey.

You need to perform 1 more call to get the data center name and correct uri for api calls.

i.e. Make an empty get call with your access token as header.
and you will get following JSON response

```
{
    "dc":"us1",
    "login_url":"https:\/\/login.mailchimp.com",
    "api_endpoint":"https:\/\/us1.api.mailchimp.com"
}
```

Hope that helps :)

reference: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/oauth2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the OAuth access tokens have the data center on the end like API keys do, you'll probably need to use the metadata endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above there's one more step. Making a call to metadata URL. Here's how to do it and retrieve DC. Remember to use your access token:

```
$access_token = YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN;
$mch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($mch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/metadata");
curl_setopt($mch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($mch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'');
curl_setopt($mch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    'User-Agent: oauth2-draft-v10',
    'Host: login.mailchimp.com',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: OAuth ' . $access_token
);

curl_setopt($mch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec ($mch);
curl_close ($mch);

print_r($response);
```